# Bixby: unable to implement login facility for my capsule

Tags: oauth-2.0, bixby, bixbystudio

As per the document I have to use oAuth 2.0 for the login implementation. I am very new to oAuth and unable to understand the concept. I would like login with my own API, No third party login facility. For example: If I have abcd website and it has login facility so I want to use that login screen.

This is the authorization code I have use in my capsule.

```
authorization {
    user {
        oauth2-authorization-code (My-Capsule-Name) {
            client-id (??) //where would i get this? 
            client-secret-key (??) //where would i get this? 
            authorize-endpoint (https://My-WEBSITE-URL/bixby_login/v3/oauth)
            token-endpoint (??) //what is this, How to implement this on server
        }
    }
}
```

We refer this:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.using-oauth

1: Unable to understand that what is client id and how would i get one?
2: Secret key is something that we have set in Config & Secret and we are using the key not it's value. is it correct?
3: Authorize End point is the URL for our website login. We have used our API to authorize user and return user's profile. Do I need to add something else? After successful login, how will we return the user to capsule?
4: Can't get token endpoint concept. How to implement this?

We are using PHP codeigniter for login form.

Comment: Consider reading about OAuth 2.0 first: https://oauth.net/2/

Comment: In the case of bixby, Do i need to register my app on bixby somewhere to get client_id and secret? Because I am not sure where do I get the client id with this document.

Comment: The client_id and secret are provided when you setup an OAuth flow.  That is not supplied by Bixby.  Please see more information on seting up an OAuth 2 application:  https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#creating-an-app

Comment: I did develop the oAuth 2.0 and got little success but stuck at last stage when my website is not redirecting proper. Here is the final url

https://myapp.oauth.aibixby.com/auth/external/cb#state=[client-secret]&access_token=[accesstoken]&token_type=bearer

Error:     
    {
         reason: "Missing required parameter"
     }

what parameter am i missing? State has parameter of my client secret key. is it Okay?

Answer (score 0):

The sample bank capsule is configured to use OAuth. You can use it as a reference.
https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-sample-bank

Comment: I am unable to redirect to bixby application. Always getting missing required parameter. I am using cURL for the redirection. Using get method and # before the first parameter. using Bearer token on header in cURL.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. Can you share your `authorization` code in your capsule? Which provider are you using now?